# Magento 2 Checkout mini-cart need to show reward point phtml block

Tags: magento-2.1, mini-cart, knockoutjs, magento2-enterprise, magento-enterprise-2

I want to show **Reward Point** content(`../vendor/magento/module-reward/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`) :

```
       <block class="Magento\Reward\Block\Tooltip\Checkout" name="reward.tooltip.checkout" template="tooltip.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="reward_type" xsi:type="string">Magento\Reward\Model\Action\OrderExtra</argument>
            </arguments>
            <action method="setWrapperClass">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">reward-checkout</argument>
            </action>
            <action method="setRewardMessage">
                <argument translate="true" name="message" xsi:type="string">Check out now and earn %1 for this order.</argument>
            </action>
            <action method="setIsGuestNote">
                <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
```

Into `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html` to show content of reward point as below :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override checkout module **Customerdata/Cart.php** file **getSectionData()** function in your custom module.

Pass new argument inside function return value,

```
public function getSectionData()
{
    $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();      
     $rewards = $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Reward\Block\Tooltip\Checkout','reward.tooltip.checkout',
        [
            'data' => ['reward_type' => 'Magento\Reward\Model\Action\OrderExtra',
                       'rewardHelper' => 'Magento\Reward\Helper\Data',
                       'customerSession' => 'Magento\Customer\Model\Session',
                       'rewardInstance' => 'Magento\Reward\Model\Reward',
                       'storeManager' => 'Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager'
                      ]
        ]);
    $rewards->setWrapperClass('reward-checkout')->setRewardMessage("Check out now and earn %1 for this order.")->setIsGuestNote(1);
    $rewards->setTemplate('Magento_Reward::tooltip.phtml'); 

    return [
        'summary_count' => $this->getSummaryCount(),                        
        'subtotal' => isset($totals['subtotal'])
            ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['subtotal']->getValue())
            : 0,
        'possible_onepage_checkout' => $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout(),
        'items' => $this->getRecentItems(),
        'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons')->toHtml(),
        'isGuestCheckoutAllowed' => $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed(),
        'rewards' => $rewards->toHtml(),
    ];
}
```

Inside your `minicart.phtml` file set your span like,

```
<span data-bind="html: getCartParam('rewards')"></span>
```

Clear cache.